# Sharing data between Android framework and app

Tags: android, frameworks, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to share data between the Android framework and an app?

I'm modifying the Android framework login component so that a variable will be saved upon login, and then later retrieved by another app. I'm trying to use SharedPreferences, and my code looks like this:

In com.android.internal.policy.impl.PasswordUnlockScreen.java, I have the following code to write to the SharedPreferences.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("mypref", "my data"
editor.commit();
```

In my other app, I have the following code to read from it.

```
Context con;
String data;
try {
  con = this.createPackageContext("com.android.internal.policy.impl", 0);
  SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  data = pref.getString("mypref", "0")
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
  data = "0";
  Log.e("No data shared", e.toString());
}
```

When I run the code, I keep getting the NameNotFoundException, as it claims the application package com.android.internal.policy.impl is not found, so my data is always "0".

How can I share data between these 2 components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at `Content Providers` from the [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), this might help you. [This is an example](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/41133/1763/page/2)